# Return SVG from a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to return an SVG file located in the same folder as the Javascript file when a function is executed.
The function is called `returnSVG`, the SVG is called `image`.

```
import image from './image.svg'

returnSVG= () => {
 return image;
}
```

But when I call it I get this: `/static/media/image.f85cba53.svg`

Comment: That's because the "./" indicates that there's more to the path, it's relative to the enclosing folder.

Comment: Thanks! Now I get another error: `Module not found: Can't resolve 'mergedStatusIcon.svg' in `'(the route of the file)'`

Comment: Is this in react or in some other context? In what sense are you trying to import it and return it?

Comment: You should take a look at this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42575712/webpack-sass-cannot-resolve-images

Comment: The purpose of the function is to return a specific SVG that later should be displayed in the HTML. In that same JS file, I call later the function with `{this.returnSVG()}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An SVG file contains a textual representation of a graphic, encoded in an XML-like syntax.

So, you cannot simply `import thing from 'filepath'` because the file contents are not a JavaScript module, a loadable binary extension, or a JSON-encoded string.

Rather than importing what cannot be imported, the correct approach would be to explicitly read the contents from the file:

```
const { readFileSync } = require('fs')
const returnSvg = (path = './image.svg') => return readFileSync(path)
```

Note that this example uses the *synchronous* version of the `fs` function to read a file. This will pause (block) all processing in NodeJS until the contents have been read.

The better solution would be to use `Promises` via `async/await` as in:

```
const { readFile } = require('fs')
const { promisify } = require('util')
const asyncReadFile = promisify(readFile)

const returnSvg = async (path = './image.svg') => {
  const data = await asyncReadFile(path)

  // since fs.readFile returns a buffer, we should probably convert it to a string.
  return data.toString() 
}
```

Using Promises and `async/await` requires that all of your processing occur within the chain of promises, so you'd need to restructure your code to:

```
returnSvg()
  .then(data => { /* do something with the file contents here. */ })
  .catch(err => console.error(`failed to read svg file: ${err}`))
```

Remember, in NodeJS, operations can be either asynchronous (via callbacks or `Promises` which `async/await` uses "*under the covers*"), or synchronous (via special "blocking" calls).

One option, if you choose to use the synchronous version would be to load all your files into your server before you call `app.listen(8080, () => console.log('listing on 8080')` but this implies you know what files will be required before you run your server and would not work for dynamically loaded files.

You might imagine doing something like:

```
const data = readSvg()
console.log(data)
```

or perhaps:

```
let data
readSvg().then(res => data = res)
console.log(data)
```

but neither will work because an asynchronous function (one defined with the `async` keyword) can only return a `Promise`.

Both attempts will not print any usable value to the console because *at the time* console.log() is called, NodeJS has no idea what the value of data *will be*.

The rule of thumb here is:

- You cannot return a value or interact with any higher context from within a Promise.
- Any manipulation of the data generated within a Promise chain, can ONLY be accessed from within its own chain.